# Source Control Repository - Per Client or Per Application?

Tags: version-control

I've recently taken over a project from another consulting firm.  I'm assuming this can happen somewhat frequently in the industry so I'm wondering how I should setup my Source Control Repository.

Should I create one repository simply for this application/client, and then create others as we do more work?

Of should I just dump everything into one single repository.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to be able to deliver the full source control repo to the customer as it is probably their work product (e.g., work-for-hire).  I recommend using one repo per customer.  I had them all in one area //depot/clients/CorpA, //depot/clients/cust-b, etc.

Made it easy for me to burn a CD with their project at the end of a contract, and by deleting the entire tree I could provide reliable assurance that I had destroyed all my copies of their IP.

Answer (score 2):

One repository per client.  This will give you a much easier method to hand off the application, change development environments, etc..

Comment: I don't plan on handling it off as we are taking it over and going to own the code base.  However, I'm sure that's what the last place thought too :)